# Async function is not executing

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, try-catch

I'm trying to fetch data from a SQL server in a Redux action.
My problem is, that what's inside the async function is absolutely not running. Neither the 'try', nor the 'catch' branch.

```
export function fetchMessages() {
    console.log("Fetching messages...");


    let tempDisp = async dispatch => {
        //This way we can show a loading screen
        console.log("Before try catch")
        dispatch(fetchMessagesBegin());
        try {
            const res = await fetch('http://185-220-204-106.cloud-xip.io:5000/messages/all');
            const json = await res.json();
            console.log("json is: ", json);
            console.log("The json object:", json);
            dispatch(fetchMessagesSuccess(json));
            return json.messages;
        }
        catch (error) {
            dispatch(fetchMessagesFailure(error));
            console.log("Error: ", error);
        }
    };

    console.log("The tempDisp is: ",tempDisp);
    return tempDisp;
}
```

The console output I get is

```
Fetching messages... main.chunk.js:292:11
The tempDisp is: function tempDisp()
```

So, console.log before async runs, before try...catch is not running, and the Error branch is also not running. I'm trying to call fetchMessages from useEffect(), but I also tried it before the rendering of the React app, same result. I can't figure out what is causing this. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108737/async-functions#comment102607697_58108737) I rewrote my code like this:

```
export const fetchMessages = messages => async (dispatch) => {
    //This way we can show a loading screen
    console.log("Before try catch");
    dispatch(fetchMessagesBegin());
    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://185-220-204-106.cloud-xip.io:5000/messages/all');
        const json = await res.json();
        console.log("json is: ", json);
        //We might not have a top level container, like 'messages'
        console.log("The json object:", json);
        dispatch(fetchMessagesSuccess(json));
        //return json.messages;
    }
    catch (error) {
        dispatch(fetchMessagesFailure(error));
        console.log("Error: ", error);
    }
}
```

It's still not working, and I don't get any console.logs anymore.

**UPDATE**
This is where I'm calling fetchMessages:

```
function App({isLoggedIn}) {
  let testingOnly = ["hello"];

  useEffect(() => {
    testingOnly = fetchMessages();

    console.log(isLoggedIn);
  });

[... React return ...]



const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
    isServerError: state.isServerError,
    serverError: state.serverError,
    loginAttempt: state.loginAttempt,
    messages: state.messages
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: You are storing your async/await in a variable `tempDisp` and then just returning it. Since it's a function, you are now returning a reference to that function, now you have to invoke it. Please show where you use `fetchMessages`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I didn't installed redux-thunk.

`import thunk from 'redux-thunk';`

then you need to add middleware to store

`let store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));`

After this, it worked.